# Generic <T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> is V required

Tags: java, generics

Came across this example in Java Complete Reference under Generics method.

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y) {
  for(int i=0; i < y.length; i++)
     if(x.equals(y[i])) return true;
        return false;
}
```

Here `V extends T` is confusing. Can we only have `<T extends Comparable<T>>` to get the job done. Because T extends some type  which means the type and its sub type. Then why we need V extends T?. Is there any special case for using `<T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T>`?

Comment: Did you mean to use `compareTo` instead of `equals` in your code?

Comment: @michalk No. If `class Abc implements Comparable<Abc>` then I can pass Abc or its sub type as type argument for T.  My understanding is `V extends T` which means V is T or its sub type is unnecessary simply we can have `static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isIn(T x, T[] y)`. I have taken this from complete reference guide and i think  there might be special use of having V. If any could you answer on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in this case, since the `V` is only used in one place, in the type of a parameter as `V[]`, and since array types are covariant, the `V` is unnecessary and the method can be written with this signature:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isIn(T x, T[] y)
```

The two method signatures would accept the same sets of arguments (assuming the caller does not specify an explicit type signature. You can see this as follows:

- Any argument that can be passed to the first signature as `V[]` can be passed to the second signature as `T[]`, since `V extends T`, so `V[] extends T[]` (array types in Java are covariant).
- Any argument that can be passed to the second signature as `T[]` can be passed to the first signature as `V[]`, because the compiler can always infer `V` as `T`, since `T` is within `V`'s bounds. Such an inference will not cause problems anywhere else since `V` is not used anywhere else.

Comment: Could you explain this line *since the V is only used in one place, in the type of a parameter as V[]* what other cases that V would be useful other than V[] in that example.

Comment: @Maghesh: For example, if the parameter type were `List<V>`, you can't replace it with `List<T>` because `List<V>` is not a subtype of `List<T>` (though you could replace it with `List<? extends T>`). If `V` were used in two places, like in a parameter and in the return type, or in two parameter types, you can't easily remove it. Or if `V` is used inside the method, it may or may not be able to be removed depending on how it is used.

Comment: I got your point just replaced `V[]` with `List<V>` and could see the use of `V entends T`.